# Non-invocable member 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Text' cannot be used like a method. in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

My c# program says this. I don't know how to fix this for I am new with c#. Pleas help me T_T. Thanks!

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void btnGenerateUserID_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox4.Text(User.GenerateUserID);   
    }

    private void btnGenerateUsername_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox5.Text(User.GenerateUsername(Name.Text, MI.Text, Lastname.Text)); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`TextBox.Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a19tt6sk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a property, its not a method. You need to assign value to the property.

```
textBox4.Text = User.GenerateUserID; //assuming its string or call User.GetUserID.ToString();
```

If `User.GetUserID` is a method then you need to call it like:

```
textBox4.Text = User.GenerateUserID();
```

If the returned value is not string, then you can call `ToString` on it like:

```
textBox4.Text = User.GenerateUserID().ToString(); //check for null before calling
                                                  //ToString
```

Do the same for:

```
textBox5.Text = User.GenerateUsername(Name.Text, MI.Text, Lastname.Text);
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir! But a new error showed. It says that "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'" and the error is placed at the designer. Can you please help me :D

Comment: @user3248531, did you miss `.Text`, seems like you are assigning string directly to textbox.

Comment: No sir. My earlier problem is solved. But now, my program said that error. And I don't know what to do because the error is pointing at the Form1.Designer.cs . And I have no experience in changing that part of c#. I'll make a thread about it so others may see the code.

Comment: @user3248531, you shouldn't change `designer.cs` manually, look at the form designer and see if it properly loads the form in VS

Answer (score 1):

You cannot "call" the `Text` property. You have to assign it a string like this:

```
textBox4.Text = User.GenerateUserID.ToString();

textBox5.Text = User.GenerateUsername(Name.Text, MI.Text, Lastname.Text);
```

---

There is an `AppendText()` method that may have confused you, if you saw that in an example. Like the name suggests, it simply appends more text to the end of whatever's already in the `TextBox`:

```
textBox4.AppendText(User.GenerateUserID.ToString());
```